# How do you control the minimum width of a table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a need in a variety of cases to ensure a table cells don't shrink past a certain width. To accomplish this I've tried a number of options with varying results. Some of the options I've tried:

- width on the td: works alright, but some browsers ignore it and it's not valid in HTML5
- CSS width inside `style=""` or stylesheet: ignored by some browsers
- image with width=X and height=1: causes the content of the td to be push up or down (by more than 1px).
- div with width=X and height=1 and float:left: this seems to work the best at the moment, although it does push the content up or down slightly

Any other ideas?

I need to it work in anything, including IE6 :( but if there are solutions that don't work in IE6, but everything else, that'd be a start anyway :)

Comment: go with divs and forget the table :)

Comment: I would love to. How would I make them act exactly like a table, including colspan and rowspan?

Comment: ..if it's a table, it's a table... I see little reason to switch to divs just so you can use the CSS to turn them back into tables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't reliably control the width of a table cell. It's best to wrap the contents in a DIV (or any other block level elements) and target that element.

Comment: But if he is presenting tabular data he should use a table. From a semantic point of view not using a table for tabular data is as bad as using a table for non-tabular data.

Comment: @Alberto Martinez I don't think @Brandon is meaning replace the entire table, but instead wrap the contents inside the cell in a div, such as <tr><td><div>foo bar</div></td></tr>

Comment: Ah, I didn't get it, indeed that would be better that using a spacer image.

Comment: That's right... use the table for the data, just wrap the data inside each cell in a block element.

Answer (score 4):

`min-width` will correctly control the minimum -- *in* browsers that support it correctly. Often times `width` can work like `min-width` in IE6-ish nonsense. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Look at min-width. Not IE6 compatible, but it'll rock in most other browsers.